# "Outside Function" issue with code when building a Reverse Park Sensor

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-4, pi4j

I am using a Pi 4 to build a reverse park sensor based on these tutorials:

https://forum.core-electronics.com.au/t/raspi-parking-sensor/3736/6

https://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Park-Sensor/

So I have set up my wiring and connections all correctly. When I reformat my code and make sure it is correct and formatted with the error: **Syntax Error: ‘return’ outside function.** Can someone please tell me how to fix this issue. I am new to coding and Raspberry Pi's and I would like some assistance please. I have tried indenting etc. but still hitting a brick wall.

The "return distance" part is the issue that keeps popping up when i try to run the code.

The code is:

```
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.cleanup()
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
TRIG = 4
ECHO = 18
GREEN = 17
YELLOW = 27
RED = 22
GPIO.setup(TRIG,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(ECHO,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(GREEN,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(YELLOW,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(RED,GPIO.OUT)
start = 1
def no_light ():
    GPIO.output(GREEN, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(YELLOW, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(RED, GPIO.LOW)

def green_light():
    GPIO.output(GREEN, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(YELLOW, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(RED, GPIO.LOW)

def yellow_light():
    GPIO.output(GREEN, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(YELLOW, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(RED, GPIO.LOW)

def red_light():
    GPIO.output(GREEN, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(YELLOW, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(RED, GPIO.HIGH)

def get_distance():
    GPIO.output(TRIG, True)
    time.sleep(0.00001)
    GPIO.output(TRIG, False)
    global start


while GPIO.input(ECHO) == False: start = time.time()
while GPIO.input(ECHO) == True: end = time.time()
signal_time = end-start
distance = signal_time / 0.000058
return distance

while True:
    distance = get_distance()
    time.sleep(0.05)
    print("distance")

if distance >= 60:
    no_light()

elif 90 > distance > 30:
    green_light()

elif 28 > distance > 16:
    yellow_light()

elif distance <=15:
    red_light()

while False:
    print ("error")


GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Please add the line number for the error. Also, this question should probably be on the Code Review Stack Exchange site.

Comment: And what is the output after you indent the code below the `get_distance` function?

Comment: The code is:
while GPIO.input(ECHO) == False: start = time.time()
while GPIO.input(ECHO) == True: end = time.time()
signal_time = end-start
distance = signal_time / 0.000058
return distance

The "return distance" part is the issue that keeps popping up when i try to run the code.

Comment: This is a general Python question.  Might be best to work through some Python tutorials.

Comment: Are you able to provide or guide me in the right path with what to do. This is quite new to me and I have no idea what to do

Comment: Google for Python tutorial and then work through the exercises.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, the `return` command is placed outside the `get_distance` function. The return command can only be used when it is in a function, so it returns the output of the function you specify. When you use `return distance`, you should keep it *in* the function or it won’t make any sense to Python. Right now, it ends with `global start`.